# jQuery crop tool with large images

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jcrop

I have a `<img>` tag which shows images. If I load large images I need to re-size it using the following CSS code

```
.resize-large-images
{
    min-width:100px;
    max-width:100%;
    width:auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

The CSS works fine. But when I use it with the `jcrop` it again loads in the actual size. What should I do to overcome this issue ? Edit `jcrop` files ? Or is there any alternatives ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(function() {
       $('#cropbox').Jcrop({ boxWidth: 450, boxHeight: 400 });
 })
```